# Windows OpenSSH Public key issue

Tags: windows, openssh, public-key-encryption

I have tried my best to get my ssh server configured although every time I try to log in with public key authorisation it comes up with a Server refused public key signature despite accepting key.

I used `ssh-keygen` to generate a key pair and then loaded the public key into the authorised_keys and send the private key over to the other account and converted it using putty.

Unfortunately I have tried my best to go through the logs but nothing jumps out, please assist if possible:

```
4188 21:06:43:039 debug3: socket:320, io:00000293E1AE1570, fd:5 
4188 21:06:43:039 debug3: fd 5 is not O_NONBLOCK
4188 21:06:43:039 debug3: pipe - r-h:332,io:00000293E1B0AC50,fd:6  w-h:260,io:00000293E1B0AD00,fd:7
4188 21:06:43:039 debug3: spawning C:\\Windows\\System32\\openssh\\sshd.exe
4188 21:06:43:052 debug3: Register child 0000000000000154 pid 6216, 0 zombies of 0
4188 21:06:43:052 debug3: close - io:00000293E1AE1570, type:1, fd:5, table_index:5
4188 21:06:43:052 debug1: Forked child 6216.
4188 21:06:43:052 debug3: close - io:00000293E1B0AD00, type:2, fd:7, table_index:7
6216 21:06:43:130 debug1: sshd version OpenSSH_7.5, without OpenSSL
6216 21:06:43:131 debug3: open - handle:0000000000000114, io:000001BDD87B1790, fd:3
6216 21:06:43:133 debug3: close - io:000001BDD87B1790, type:2, fd:3, table_index:3
6216 21:06:43:133 debug1: private host key #0: ssh-ed25519 SHA256:NjgKQSG8Ij4NAF1BFLVudb+dZoMpZMmOUPozaHmbFz4
6216 21:06:43:137 debug1: child socket: 320
6216 21:06:43:137 debug1: child startup_pipe: 260
6216 21:06:43:138 Connection from 192.168.1.3 port 49196 on 192.168.1.7 port 22
6216 21:06:43:138 debug1: Client protocol version 2.0; client software version PuTTY_Release_0.70
6216 21:06:43:138 debug1: no match: PuTTY_Release_0.70
6216 21:06:43:138 debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.5
6216 21:06:43:138 debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
6216 21:06:43:138 debug1: list_hostkey_types: ssh-ed25519
6216 21:06:43:141 debug3: send packet: type 20
6216 21:06:43:141 debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
6216 21:06:43:143 debug3: receive packet: type 20
6216 21:06:43:143 debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
6216 21:06:43:144 debug2: local server KEXINIT proposal
6216 21:06:43:144 debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org
6216 21:06:43:144 debug2: host key algorithms: ssh-ed25519
6216 21:06:43:144 debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr
6216 21:06:43:144 debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr
6216 21:06:43:144 debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
6216 21:06:43:144 debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
6216 21:06:43:144 debug2: compression ctos: none
6216 21:06:43:144 debug2: compression stoc: none
6216 21:06:43:144 debug2: languages ctos: 
6216 21:06:43:144 debug2: languages stoc: 
6216 21:06:43:144 debug2: first_kex_follows 0 
6216 21:06:43:144 debug2: reserved 0 
6216 21:06:43:144 debug2: peer client KEXINIT proposal
6216 21:06:43:144 debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,rsa2048-sha256,rsa1024-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
6216 21:06:43:144 debug2: host key algorithms: ssh-ed25519,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ssh-rsa,ssh-dss
6216 21:06:43:144 debug2: ciphers ctos: aes256-ctr,aes256-cbc,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se,aes192-ctr,aes192-cbc,aes128-ctr,aes128-cbc,chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,blowfish-ctr,blowfish-cbc,3des-ctr,3des-cbc,arcfour256,arcfour128
6216 21:06:43:144 debug2: ciphers stoc: aes256-ctr,aes256-cbc,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se,aes192-ctr,aes192-cbc,aes128-ctr,aes128-cbc,chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,blowfish-ctr,blowfish-cbc,3des-ctr,3des-cbc,arcfour256,arcfour128
6216 21:06:43:144 debug2: MACs ctos: hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha1,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com
6216 21:06:43:144 debug2: MACs stoc: hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha1,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com
6216 21:06:43:144 debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib
6216 21:06:43:144 debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib
6216 21:06:43:144 debug2: languages ctos: 
6216 21:06:43:144 debug2: languages stoc: 
6216 21:06:43:144 debug2: first_kex_follows 0 
6216 21:06:43:144 debug2: reserved 0 
6216 21:06:43:144 debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org
6216 21:06:43:144 debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ssh-ed25519
6216 21:06:43:144 debug1: kex: client->server cipher: aes256-ctr MAC: hmac-sha2-256 compression: none
6216 21:06:43:144 debug1: kex: server->client cipher: aes256-ctr MAC: hmac-sha2-256 compression: none
6216 21:06:43:144 debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_INIT
6216 21:06:43:149 debug3: receive packet: type 30
6216 21:06:43:153 debug3: send packet: type 31
6216 21:06:43:153 debug3: send packet: type 21
6216 21:06:43:153 debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1
6216 21:06:43:153 debug1: rekey after 4294967296 blocks
6216 21:06:43:153 debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
6216 21:06:43:153 debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
6216 21:06:43:445 debug3: receive packet: type 21
6216 21:06:43:445 debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
6216 21:06:43:445 debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0
6216 21:06:43:445 debug1: rekey after 4294967296 blocks
6216 21:06:43:445 debug1: KEX done
6216 21:06:43:445 debug3: receive packet: type 5
6216 21:06:43:445 debug3: send packet: type 6
6216 21:06:46:862 debug3: receive packet: type 50
6216 21:06:46:862 debug1: userauth-request for user Admin service ssh-connection method none
6216 21:06:46:862 debug1: attempt 0 failures 0
6216 21:06:46:862 debug2: parse_server_config: config reprocess config len 404
6216 21:06:46:863 debug2: input_userauth_request: setting up authctxt for Admin
6216 21:06:46:863 debug2: input_userauth_request: try method none
6216 21:06:46:863 Failed none for Admin from 192.168.1.3 port 49196 ssh2
6216 21:06:46:863 debug3: userauth_finish: failure partial=0 next methods="publickey,keyboard-interactive"
6216 21:06:46:863 debug3: send packet: type 51
6216 21:06:46:864 debug3: receive packet: type 50
6216 21:06:46:864 debug1: userauth-request for user Admin service ssh-connection method publickey
6216 21:06:46:864 debug1: attempt 1 failures 0
6216 21:06:46:864 debug2: input_userauth_request: try method publickey
6216 21:06:46:864 debug1: userauth_pubkey: test whether pkalg/pkblob are acceptable for ED25519 SHA256:GXSt/UnCweDJklx4mgiPkNn4DjHUbEGfpTMlj7HGK8o
6216 21:06:46:864 debug1: trying public key file C:\\Users\\Admin\\.ssh/authorized_keys
6216 21:06:46:865 debug1: matching key found: file C:\\Users\\Admin\\.ssh/authorized_keys, line 1 ED25519 SHA256:GXSt/UnCweDJklx4mgiPkNn4DjHUbEGfpTMlj7HGK8o
6216 21:06:46:865 debug3: send packet: type 60
6216 21:06:46:865 debug2: userauth_pubkey: authenticated 0 pkalg ssh-ed25519
6216 21:06:46:865 Postponed publickey for Admin from 192.168.1.3 port 49196 ssh2
6216 21:06:47:117 debug3: receive packet: type 50
6216 21:06:47:117 debug1: userauth-request for user Admin service ssh-connection method publickey
6216 21:06:47:117 debug1: attempt 2 failures 0
6216 21:06:47:117 debug2: input_userauth_request: try method publickey
6216 21:06:47:117 debug3: userauth_pubkey: have signature for ED25519 SHA256:GXSt/UnCweDJklx4mgiPkNn4DjHUbEGfpTMlj7HGK8o
6216 21:06:47:117 debug1: trying public key file C:\\Users\\Admin\\.ssh/authorized_keys
6216 21:06:47:117 debug1: matching key found: file C:\\Users\\Admin\\.ssh/authorized_keys, line 1 ED25519 SHA256:GXSt/UnCweDJklx4mgiPkNn4DjHUbEGfpTMlj7HGK8o
6216 21:06:47:117 debug3: socket:0, socktype:1, io:000001BDD8805290, fd:5 
6216 21:06:47:138 debug2: userauth_pubkey: authenticated 0 pkalg ssh-ed25519
6216 21:06:47:138 Failed publickey for Admin from 192.168.1.3 port 49196 ssh2: ED25519 SHA256:GXSt/UnCweDJklx4mgiPkNn4DjHUbEGfpTMlj7HGK8o
6216 21:06:47:138 debug3: userauth_finish: failure partial=0 next methods="publickey,keyboard-interactive"
6216 21:06:47:138 debug3: send packet: type 51
6216 21:06:47:139 debug3: receive packet: type 50
6216 21:06:47:139 debug1: userauth-request for user Admin service ssh-connection method keyboard-interactive
6216 21:06:47:139 debug1: attempt 3 failures 1
6216 21:06:47:139 debug2: input_userauth_request: try method keyboard-interactive
6216 21:06:47:139 debug1: keyboard-interactive devs 
6216 21:06:47:139 debug1: auth2_challenge: user=Admin devs=
6216 21:06:47:139 debug1: kbdint_alloc: devices ''
6216 21:06:47:139 debug2: auth2_challenge_start: devices 
6216 21:06:47:139 Failed keyboard-interactive for Admin from 192.168.1.3 port 49196 ssh2
6216 21:06:47:139 debug3: userauth_finish: failure partial=0 next methods="publickey,keyboard-interactive"
6216 21:06:47:139 debug3: send packet: type 51
6216 21:06:47:140 debug3: receive packet: type 1
6216 21:06:47:140 error: Received disconnect from 192.168.1.3 port 49196:14: No supported authentication methods available
6216 21:06:47:140 Disconnected from authenticating user Admin 192.168.1.3 port 49196
6216 21:06:47:140 debug1: do_cleanup
4188 21:06:47:142 debug3: close - io:00000293E1B0AC50, type:2, fd:6, table_index:6
4188 21:06:47:153 debug3: zombie'ing child at index 0, 0 zombies of 1
4188 21:06:47:153 debug3: Unregister child at index 0, 1 zombies of 1
```

Upon further review of the above log, the point that sticks out to me after the public key is used the first time it is postponed and then after trying again it fails. Does anyone have an idea at what would b e causing these postpones (or eventual fails)?

EDIT : Updated the host key list as per below comment.

Comment: The failure to open key files stands out to me. Is the box able to find it's own keys?

Comment: @davidgo The only lines I can see about missing keys are for the `RSA` and `DSA` keys. This is due to currently the sever is only set up with a `ed25519` as I am just running the base encryption, This is currently in a test environment so just having `ed25519` set up is enough for now. 

If there are other lines that I have missed please let me know, Although if the server keys could not be found I do not think I would get this far, in fact I am unsure if the server could even start in that condition?

Thanks for the response though.

Comment: @davidgo - I updated the host key definitions, please let me know if anything else jumps out.